# UILabel wrapping incorrectly in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, xcode

Here I have a `UICollectionViewCell`, with a `UILabel`. My labels are character wrapping long words onto a second line. I thought autoshrink would take precedence over line breaks, since "Cappuccino" can easily be autoshrunk onto just 1 line. I even have Word Wrap on.

Why is this label being character wrapped as opposed to autoshrunk with a minimum font size?

**EDIT:** I'm aware that `numberOfLines` needs to be > 0, but programmatically determining `numberOfLines` based on a label's text and bounding rect doesn't consider autoshrink. I can check if the font size with 1 line != my desired font size, and adjust `numberOfLines` by guessing, but there's no `isTruncated` property for me to tell whether the line has broken. So the right question is, how can I programmatically account for autoshrink while determining an appropriate `numberOfLines`?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you must set a number of lignes `> 0` when using this config for all UI text containers.